# How can I call an object's method from another object?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm creating custom UI components using ES6 classes doing something like this:

```
class Dropdown {

    constructor(dropdown) {
        this.dropdown = dropdown;
        this._init();
    }

    _init() {
        //init component
    }

    setValue(val) {
        //"public" method I want to use from another class
    }
}
```

And when the page load I initiate the components like this:

```
let dropdown = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");
if (dropdown) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(dropdown, (element) => {
        let DropDownEl = new Dropdown(element);
    });
}
```

But now I need to acces a method of one of these classes from another one. In this case, I need to access a method to set the value of the dropdown 
based on a URL parameter, so I would like to do something like:

```
class SearchPage {
//SearchPage is a class and a DOM element with different components (like the dropdown) that I use as filters. This class will listen to the dispached events
//from these filters to make the Ajax requests.

    constructor() {
        this._page = document.querySelector(".search-page")
        let dropdown = this._page.querySelector(".dropdown);
        //Previously I import the class into the file            
        this.dropdown = new Dropdown(dropdown);
    }

    setValues(val) {

        this.dropdown.setValue(val);
        //Set other components' values...
    }

}
```

But when I create this instance, another dropdown is added to the page, which I don't want.

I think an alternative is to create the components this way, inside other ones, and not like in the first piece of code. Is this a valid way? Should I create another Dropdown class that inherits from the original one?

Comment: "*When the page load I initiate the components like this*" - why? What do they do on their own? Who uses the `let DropDownEl`s and calls their public methods?

Comment: @Bergi No one, actually. It is the way to show custom element and not the default one. Should I change it?

Comment: @Bergi On their one will dispatch events.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to store the `Dropdown` instance on the element to avoid re-creating it:

```
class Dropdown {
    constructor(element) {
        if (element.dropdown instanceof Dropdown)
            return element.dropdown;
        this.element = element;
        element.dropdown = this;

        //init component
    }
    …
}
```

Comment: What is "element" here? Is it the dropdown?

Comment: @IsmaelOrdás Yes, I renamed it to the more fitting `element`. A `SearchPage` has a `dropdown`, a `Dropdown` has a… `element`, not another `dropdown`.

Comment: I still don't see it, because what I pass to the constructor is a DOM element. Could you provide another usage example? 
Also, creating the instance inside its parent's object is a valid solution? (The SearchPage class, in this case) Instead of creating when the page load.

Comment: @IsmaelOrdás Exactly, it's passed a DOM element, which is why the parameter is named `element`. Yes, creating instances inside other instances is totally valid. Whether your complete application architecture is valid or not I cannot judge from the small snippet you gave. It's just a straightforward and non-intensive solution to make sure that you get the same `Dropdown` instance from the constructor call as long as you pass the same element.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions, but how can you access element.dropdown in your example if you are passing a DOM element and not an object?

Comment: I just stored a property on the DOM element. It's also an object.